# Getting a dropdownlist to check a checkbox in asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, drop-down-menu

```
<input runat ="server" type ="checkbox" id="helprequest" />     
<label for="helprequest">Help request</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="options" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkHelpRequest">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Windows"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Macintosh"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Linux"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In my codebehind, I have

```
protected void checkHelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    helprequest.Checked = true;
}
```

But when I select something on the dropdownlist, the checkbox, does not get marked as checked, how do I get the checkbox to appear as checked when I change the index on a dropdownlist?

Comment: Do you have autopostback="true" set on this control? You might also want to investigate other ways of doing this, for example jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DropDownList` does not have `AutoPostBack='true'` set.  Without setting this, your dropdown will not post back when you change the selected index.

Just change it to:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="options" 
      runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkHelpRequest">
```

Without setting this, your `checkHelpRequest` method will still be called when your drop down changes index, but only after a postback is caused by **some other control**, like a button, or another DropDownList that *does* have AutoPostBack set.