# Import checked status from a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox

I'm trying to make this code work:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="statusChk" runat="server" Visible="true" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# status("de_cancel") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
```

What i'm trying to do is to retrieve the answer from the *status* function (which returns bool when i give a string) that i created in the c# source.
Doesn't give me compile error, but doesn't work. *Edit: And btw, this is inside in a GridView*

This works:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("de_cancel") %>'></asp:Label>
```

But this is **NOT** what I'm looking for.

Sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is in a grid view, or some other repeater.

In that case, try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# status(Eval("de_cancel")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

this is essentially calling your `status()` method and passing in the value of `de_cancel`

You may have to `convert` `de_cancel` inside your `status` method though as `Eval` returns an object.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning, yes this is in a GridView. Your code isnt doing what i want, and even correcting:
`<asp:CheckBox ID="statusChk" runat="server" Visible="true" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Eval(status("de_cancel"))%>'></asp:CheckBox>`
or
`<asp:CheckBox ID="statusChk" runat="server" Visible="true" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#status(Eval("de_cancel"))%>'></asp:CheckBox>`

Both giving me an error.

Comment: Just for the future generations, the final answer: `<asp:CheckBox ID="statusChk" runat="server" Visible="true" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#status(Convert.ToString(Eval("de_cancel")))%>'></asp:CheckBox>`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in the codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get your string variable and use it as input here
        statusChk.Checked = status("de_cancel"); 
    }

    protected bool status(string strStatus)
    {
        if (strStatus == "de_cancel")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This will occur when the page loads. There are other event handlers you may want to use - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s(v=vs.90).aspx

Here is an example of how an event handler (*OnSelectedIndexChanged*) can be used to set a checkbox when a drop-down value is changed. As the accepted answer points out, you will need to set the *AutoPostBack="true"* option on the control if you want the event handler method to fire (and the page to refresh) when a control is changed:

[Getting a dropdownlist to check a checkbox in asp.net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448044/getting-a-dropdownlist-to-check-a-checkbox-in-asp-net-c)

Also, just looking at your code it looks like you might be using databinding, e.g. with a *Repeater* or *ListView*. In this case, please the examples for the ItemDataBound event handler below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c12065/ASPNET-Tip-Use-the-ItemDataBound-Event-of-a-Repeater.htm

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning, yes this is in a GridView. So the statusChk doesn't exist in the Page_Load.
I read and tried to reproduce what ur 2 last links did, and couldnt make it, maybe i'm too dumb. (I'll keep trying) :/

Comment: That's okay - I was probably over-complicating it. Post your code if you'd like me to take a look.

Comment: I already get the answer for this, but many thanks for your attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Darren tip, i was able to do it. Here what i did to make it work:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="statusChk" runat="server" Visible="true" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#status(Convert.ToString(Eval("de_cancel")))%>'></asp:CheckBox>
```

Thanks everyone. ;)

Comment: You know, I did say in the answer that you would need to convert your `de_cancel`......Essentially this is exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: Not exactly, but yes your tip was crucial for the answer. I tried to give you a "point" showing that your answer was useful, but I couldn't because my account is new. Instead I gave you owner of the accepted answer.